# What does : mean in matlab syntax and how to translate that to python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am trying to adapt some matlab code into python and the specific line is this

```
0:1/2047:1
```

What is the python equivalent of the above line?
I am interpreting it as

```
a = np.arange(1,2048,1)
b = 1/a[::-1]
```

but I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: What do  you not understand from the MATLAB language documentation?

Comment: I dont know what to call this ```0:1/2047:1``` to be able to search MATLAB docs.

Comment: I don't know, because *I* haven't looked it up, either.  I recognize the syntax, but that's all.  I'm trying to get OP to upgrade this into a fully valid question.

Comment: HI Prune, I do not speak MATLAB so i dont have the vocabulary to frame a "proper" question. Can you explain what that syntax is achieving?

Comment: Here’s the MATLAB doc for that syntax: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  However, since @CrisLuengo solved your problem, the meta-issues are moot.

Comment: MATLAB is using the `start: step: stop` order, in contrast to the python/numpy `start, stop, step` order.  You can deduce that from the values and what makes sense.

Comment: @hpaulj: Aaah! Super! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an Octave session (free source)

```
>> 1:5
ans =

   1   2   3   4   5

>> 1:.5:5
ans =

 Columns 1 through 7:

    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000

 Columns 8 and 9:

    4.5000    5.0000
```

Clearly this a variante on the numpy `np.arange`.

There's also a `linspace` which is even closer to the `numpy` version (MATLAB's was first):

```
>> linspace(1,5,10)
ans =

 Columns 1 through 8:

   1.0000   1.4444   1.8889   2.3333   2.7778   3.2222   3.6667   4.1111

 Columns 9 and 10:

   4.5556   5.0000
```